# How to fix it when image in html page is not displayed but its working when the same html page is included in some another html page?

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a web application which has a separate file for header specifications called head.php. I have included this file in rest of my web pages. Now, when I open head.php in browser, it doesn't display any of the images mentioned in it. 
Whereas, when I open rest of the pages that include head.php in browser, the images mentioned in head.php are displayed properly.
How should I fix it ??

I have tried copying images in the same folder. But I don't think that there is any issue in the url part, or else images wouldn't be shown at all in any webpage.
Her's the code of head.php :

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
        #foot{
            height:50px;
            width:100%;
            margin-top:140px;
            position:relative;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            background-image:url("img/w4.jpg");
        }
        p{
            color:white;
            float:right;
            padding-right:20px;
            font-size:18px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <footer>
    <div id="foot">
        <p>Leave Management Portal</p>
    </div>
    </footer>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [ask]. If you don't add sufficient relevant code for your particular issue in the question, chances of getting help around here are close to `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img/w4.jpg` is a relative path. It is saying "inside the images folder *inside the current folder*, there is a w4.jpg image."

If you change locations say from `mysite.com/` to `mysite.com/otherpage` your relative path will be looking for `/otherpage/img/w4.jpg`.

You can add a slash at the beginning to say "start at the root" `/img/w4.jpg` or you can use a PHP method to always point to the same directory no matter where you are in your website directory structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its quite useful.The issue is not with the url as the images in head.php are getting displayed when i open those pages that include head,php. But when i directly open head.php, none of the images are working.

Comment: Where is head.php in your directory structure? The same place from where you're opening the pages?

Comment: The structure is like: the project folder (leave) that contains rest of the pages and another folder (includes) that contains head.php. Pathname that I write in browser is localhost/leave/includes/head.php where leave folder contains rest of the pages and a folder named "includes". This 'includes' folder contains head.php.

Comment: Exactly so when you open `normalPage.php` your image path is `localhost/leave/img/w4.jpg` but when you open `head.php` because it is in `/includes` your image path is `localhost/leave/includes/img/w4.jpg`

Comment: The relative path is relative to the URL that is currently requesting the asset not the location of the original file include.

Comment: yeah ....... very accurate, thanks a lot for your help. :) :) . I tried it after changing the path name and its working fine now. Thank you so much :)